# deceptive site ahead warning on chrome for my website

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I'm hosting a side project with firebase, and for some reason I'm getting a warning from chrome when I try to visit it (but not from Firefox). I scanned the website for malware with multiple services (sucuri, scanner.pcrisk), and couldn't find anything. The website is just a webpage, no server. Can anybody help me understand what is going on?

Website:
https://netflix-app-4bcc7.web.app/

[image]

Notably, on Firefox it's not blocked by the padlock symbol has a warning indicator, which when I click on tells me that some of the content is not secure and there is mixed content. Have trouble understanding what this means though

[image]

Comment: The "padlock" in FF doesn't carry any information about the security of the content - it just informs about the presence, absence or status of the site's SSL certificate.

Comment: Hi Klondike. Did you solve your issue? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be that your website is mimicking the actual Netflix site. Chrome might have noticed this, and thus has determined that your website could be a phishing site.

If this is a side project, perhaps changing the website name and especially the url to something more unique will resolve this issue.